# How to make my property convention ignore a mapping that has formula?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Can someone tell me how to make my property convention ignore a mapping that has formula?

This is the entity:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual string FirstName {get; set;}
    public virtual string LastName {get; set;}
    public virtual string FullName {get; set;}
}
```

This is the mapping:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
        Map(x => x.FullName).Formula("first_name || ' ' || last_name");
    }
}
```

I want my property convention to ignore the FullName property.
Thanks for helping

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are asking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your convention implementing IConventionAcceptance (or the equivalent IPropertyConventionAcceptance)? From there, within the Accept method, you can access the "Formula" property and return true/false appropriately. This will prevent your convention from processing the property.